# How Instagram minify the css?

Tags: javascript

I looked at the source of Instagram and see that the classes minified and renamed.

How they do it? is it something they develop or any webpack plugin?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I know that Facebook uses React and does this on the webpack side. You can read more about it in this link: https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda